# Manipulating SQLite date and time

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have been doing some work using sql lite, here is my table structure:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...... createdDate TEXT NOT NULL, updatedDate TEXT)', [], null,onError);
```

When I insert date I use for example this format: '2013-8-19 7:47:57'. I can tell its ok because I get no error messages and i see the data using chrome developer tools. However when I try to format the date using strftime I get a undefined. For example this does not work and gives a undefined:

```
SELECT *, strftime('%m', createdDate) as `fm`
```

what I am trying to do just get the month: 01-12. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tired `SELECT strftime('%m', datefield) FROM table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [correct format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) would not be `2013-8-19 7:47:57` but `2013-08-19 07:47:57`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comma and the quotes might be messing you up

Try this:
`SELECT * strftime('%m', createdDate) as fm`

Check the docs [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and a nice tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm).